# How to enable preview in dired-preview

Tags: dired

Having watched

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_2NAbPp_0zY

I came across the option of Previewing a directory in dired mode and would like to implement this feature but can't work out how to do it.
I have installed https://protesilaos.com/emacs/dired-preview

but can't work out how to actually invoke preview. I can't see how to define a key binding to start preview mode.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: That you "can't work out" how to do something isn't a clear question. Please be specific. Show/say exactly what you tried, what you saw, what you saw instead, and what was unclear. Specifics. And only one question per post, please. If there is more than one specific thing that you don't understand, post those questions separately.

Comment: Thanks for the 'helpful' guidance.

Comment: Open a directory with `dired` using e.g. `C-x C-f /path/to/some/directory`, enable the mode with `M-x dired-preview-mode` and then arrow up and down in the directory and watch the preview in the other window. IME, it can only preview text files (no PDF, no images).

Comment: Many thanks, I have it working now. Is this only effective on the current dired window?